# Create a new column after dataframe gets df.style

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I'm trying to add a new column after dataframe gets df.style.
However, I got an error message:

> 'Styler' object does not support item assignment

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,3,1], [3,7,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))

subsets = pd.IndexSlice[:, 'A']
df2 = df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: yellow', subset = subsets)
df2['sum'] = None
```

Below is what I want to achieve:

[image: Link]

How can I convert df2 to a real dataframe that I can edit? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot processing styler object by add data processing like add new column, you need add it before:

```
df2['sum'] = None
subsets = pd.IndexSlice[:, 'A']
df2 = df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: yellow', subset = subsets)
```